# How to construct a Tensor with values at given indices inside graph mode?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor

I have a 1D tensor of length 128 with logits in it.
For a custom loss, I'm trying to replace the 3 highest values with 1.0 and replace the rest with 0.0. This is inside a @tf.function, so I can't convert it to numpy and do the manipulation there.

I've come up with:

```
top_3 = tf.math.top_k(code, k=3)
indices = top_3.indices    
updates = tf.ones_like(indices)
new_code = tf.scatter_nd(indices, updates, tf.constant([128]))
```

But it gives me the error:

```
ValueError: Dimensions [3,1) of input[shape=[?]] = [] must match dimensions [0,1) of updates[shape=[3]] = [3]: Shapes must be equal rank, but are 0 and 1 for '{{node ScatterNd}} = ScatterNd[T=DT_INT32, Tindices=DT_INT32](TopKV2:1, ones_like_1, Const_3)' with input shapes: [3], [3], [1].
```

which I don't understand, because indices should have length 3, and so does updates. Whats the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
import tensorflow as tf

code = tf.random.normal((128,))
top_3 = tf.math.top_k(code, k=3)
indices = top_3.indices

updates = tf.ones_like(indices, dtype=tf.float32)
new_code = tf.zeros_like(code)
new_code = tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(new_code, indices[..., None], updates)
print(new_code)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this works! What does indices[..., None] do? Why can't I use the indices directly?

Comment: It just adds a new dimension to the tensor.. Check here: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/tensor_scatter_nd_update